# unique_ptr to nullptr is uncopyable

Tags: c++, vector, null, unique-ptr

It looks like creating nested vectors of unique_ptr to null throws *attempting to reference a deleted function*. I believe this is because it's trying to copy the vector unique_ptr(nullptr)'s and unique_ptr(nullptr) is uncopyable.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
struct Foo {
};
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> foo(5, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>(5));
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/SkvGkVYoQ

I'm not sure how to proceed. I just need a multi-dimensional array of nullptr's, and it'd be swell if they'd be unique - shared_ptr isn't needed other than fixing this issue.

Comment: It's nothing to do with nullptr - unique_ptr itself is uncopyable, as its name suggests.

Comment: Right. So how would I go about creating a multi-dimensional array of unique_ptr's by defining the default size?

Comment: Don't use the copy-from-element ctor of `std::vector` make the first dimension, then use ranged for to resize the inside dimension of each vector.

Comment: Why are you using `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>` instead of just `vector<Foo>`?

Comment: I'd like to assign ownership of Foo to the vector at some future point `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foo; foo.at(2) = std::make_unique<Foo>();`. That's why they're nullptr's at the moment.

Comment: @TMoore, but that still doesn't explain why you need multi dimensional array. you only need them in separate dimensions if you need to keep let's say 10 foo object together while keeping let's say another 2 foo object separate in the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is simply not copyable. That's unrelated to the `nullptr`. Simplest workaround is to just use a single dimensional array and map the dimensions.

Then you can do something like:

```
for (std::size_t j = 0; i < 5; ++j) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::size_t index = j*5+i;
        foo.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    }
}
```

(You could apply a similar pattern with nested `std::vector`s but this way it's probably better anyway in regards to cache locality etc.)

Comment: Indeed, this is not only simpler, it is also faster (one indirection only, less allocations...) and has a smaller memory footprint than a nested `std::vector`. Nested `std::vector` should only ever be used if you really have a vector of unpredictable, different sizes each.

Comment: Agreed; however, I couldn't use `std::array<Foo, n>` since I didn't know the size at compliation: n is passed via constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if you ever need to nest multiple vectors due to each nested vector element within the vector having a different size, then you can use the `std::move` to move unique ptrs from one vector to another.

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> container1;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> container2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        container1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        container2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> containers;
    containers.emplace_back(std::move(container1));
    containers.emplace_back(std::move(container2));

    return 0;
```

Mapping is the fastest solution though.